# Unable to use `lists` in many to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

My Laravel version is 5.5.13.

I created a many to many relationship between User model and Pet model. Pets can belong to multiple users.

I am trying to do in my `update` method in controller, get a list of all associated user ids. So I tried:

```
public function update(Request $request, Pet $pet)
{
    dd($pet->users()->lists('id'));
    $pet->update($request->all());
    return response()->json($pet, 200);
}
```

However I get:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::lists()

It seems there is no `lists()`.

If I do `dd($pet->users())` it gives no error and shows a lot of information.

*May you please help to get this `lists()` to work.

My relationship in `Pet` model is:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}
```

And my relatinship in `User` model is:

```
public function pets()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Pet');
}
```

Here is my migration for the pivot:

```
Schema::create('pet_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('pet_id')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->foreign('pet_id')->references('id')->on('pets')->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Comment: what about `$pet->users()->get()->lists('id')` ? since `->users()` is a relation class instead of an array.

Comment: wah thanks, i should have checked the api before commenting.

Comment: Thanks @BagusTesa - I'm guilty of that too :( I'm real new to laravel though so I'm still learning how to read the and explore the docs :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list()` is no more available in Laravel. Alternatively you can use `pluck()` and pluck all items like this `pluck()->all();`

```
pluck('key')->all();
pluck()->all();
```

Reference [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-pluck)

Answer (score 1):

laravel has deprecated the lists() method use pluck instead.

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/lists-deprecated-replacement